# Exim config rewrite rule allowing FROM any user @ their domain only?

Tags: configuration, exim

I'm looking for a solution to replace cPanel's "Rewrite From Header" tweak, because I have one or possibly more client(s) with LOCAL Microsoft Exchange servers running in their office and they want to SMTP through our server.  The problem is: MS Exchange only uses a SINGLE SMTP user no matter how many email accounts it holds.

cPanel's "Rewrite From Header" tweak rewrites all FROM addresses to match the actual sender, therefore in case of a local MS Exchange server, say user1@domain.com authenticates to our SMTP and then sends an email FROM user2@domain.com then our server rewrites it back to user1@domain.com and so forth for all email users.

This is normally a good thing, but this MS Exchange server needs to be able to send as user2@domain.com, user3@domain.com, user4@domain.com even if the only authentication they can do is with user1@domain.com

I took a look at exim rewrite patterns but I have zero experience with it, so any help in writing a generic rewrite rule to solve the following two conditions at once would be very much appreciated and could be beneficial and used by thousands of other web servers too...

**REWRITE RULE CONDITIONS I NEED:**

**1)** PHP scripts cannot forge FROM headers as an account's domain the script does not originate from.  This is already achieved by cPanel's "Rewrite From Header" tweak.

**2)** External SMTP users can only forge FROM headers as the account's domain they authenticated with, meaning they could send FROM any-user@their-domain-only.com.  This is against cPanel's "Rewrite From Header" tweak.

So I need a *combination/adaptation of cPanel's tweak* to allow for the 2 conditions at once.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own Perl script and annexing it to WHM's "Rewrite From: header" tweak found in /etc/exim.pl.local